# Collection-repeat not rendering data into ion list view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to migrate from ng-repeat to collection-repeat . But the problem   is its not working. Data is not at all rendering. I tried all the codepen's provided and tried with collection-item-height and width but no use.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to a codepen with your problem in it?